# Windows Server Essentials 2012 resolving DNS to IPV6

Tags: dns, ipv6, windows-server-2012, ipv4

I am having an issue when I ping the server by name it resolves into an IPV6 address. I have disabled IPv6 resolution in the DNS settings on the server, then reset the DNS service on the server and still get that. On each pc joined to the domain as well I have reset the nics and still resolves to IPv6. What else can I try?

Comment: Can you disable IPv6 altogether?

Comment: Is there a problem with the hostname resolving to IPv6?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen It's Windows, you can't disable IPv6 and shouldn't attempt to, as it would break many Windows components (not to mention leave you without full Internet connectivity).

Comment: I don't want to disable IPV6, I want the IPV4 resolve to take priority

Comment: @Michael Hampton Thank you. Didn't realize that. OP should answer to grawity's question though.

Comment: See [KB929852](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929852/guidance-for-configuring-ipv6-in-windows-for-advanced-users).